# Need to identify an old Zinsco breaker

Tags: electrical

Can anyone identify these old Zinsco breakers?  I need to add one 20 amp breaker to this panel.   thanks!
[image: zinsco breakers]

[image: old zinsco breakers]

Comment: why don't you read the manufacturer's labels on the breakers?

Comment: I'd urge you to strongly consider replacing that whole panel, rather than adding a breaker to it.  Zinscos are known to have problems, and sometimes start fires.  You can read more about it here: https://inspectapedia.com/electric/Zinsco_Electrical_Panels.php

Comment: Especially since the right copper bus thing seems to have burn marks along its left side...

Comment: Is this a main panel or a subpanel?  Can you post photos showing the full panel? How big is the panel's box? (height by width is fine)

Comment: You will find many of the electricians here _urgently_ pleading with you to replace the whole panel so your house doesn't burn down. Also, because of the issues, you may not be able to buy them any more...

Comment: Upvoted for providing pictures. Will add a voice to "replace, rather than continue to use/add to this panel, or potential fire-starter." *i.e.* you may be able to find a breaker, but it's a really bad idea, IMHO. You've got scorch marks already.

Comment: Thank you all for the amazing input!  I will certainly replace this old panel.  Why risk a fire to save a few bucks.  You guys might have saved a fire.  Keep up the good work - you all make a big difference.  Thank you again!

Comment: The appropriate way to say "thank you" is to up vote the answer(s) (which you may have done) and click the check mark next to the one that helps you the most. Take the [tour] and browse through the [help] - I'm going to guess you're going to have more questions as you undertake your journey...

Comment: Pay close heed to ThreePhaseEel’s questions. The Eel is a panel expert and can save you money and time.

Answer (score 1):

That is an old Zinsco breaker model called "Magnetrip" and there's more than one style. Yours has a forked bus which requires screw terminals top and bottom.

You will not find these new but there are companies who salvage old breakers and load test them and certify them. You will need to source replacements that way.

Still, there is some risk. You really should strongly consider replacing the panel, there will come a day when you can't get replacements at all.

P.S.- there is usually a (safety related) reason when breakers and panels are discontinued...

Comment: P.S.- what's the deal with that 15 amp breaker on the left. It doesn't look like it is attached to the bus. Is it in service that way?

Comment: neither of the 15 amp breakers look like they are installed properly... get an electrician before you have a fire.

Comment: I think that left 15A is connected to that black wire that's screwed to the right bus for some reason.  Makes me wonder if the two of them are serving an MWBC.

Comment: Thank you all for the amazing input!  I will certainly replace this old panel.  Why risk a fire to save a few bucks.  You guys might have saved a fire.  Keep up the good work - you all make a big difference.  Thank you again!